# Server refusing access from every host except itself

Tags: hosts

I have media content on a hosted server that I want to be accessed by another domain.

In the configuration file, even if I "Allow from all," all hosts except itself will fetch the hosting company's generic landing page, which puzzles me.

I test it with curl, with the command:

```
curl -H "Host: anything.com" http://mydomain.com
```

and it just shows the hosting company's page.

If I do:

```
curl -H "Host: mydomain.com" http://mydomain.com
```

it will show my content.

How do I allow other hosts to access my content? I thought it would work with "Allow" in .htaccess, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 3):

Read up on http host headers. It's doing exactly what it should. You need to have your hosting company add another host header for your new domain.

Comment: ah, the `Host:` header is meant to tell the server what host you are looking for, instead of reading it from the URL, right? it's not in anyway like the `referrer` +1

Answer (score 0):

is the domain name new? it sounds to me like the DNS records haven't quite propagated and example.com is still pointing to the hosting site's parked domain.

try doing `dig example.com` to see what information comes up, and if that is accurate. also, try going right to the ip address of your webhost.

as Mark pointed out, `Host` headers don't do what you think they do, you're telling your server that you want the page for `anything.com` not that you are browsing from `anything.com`

if you're still having problems browsing your site, i strongly suspect it's DNS 'propagation' issues.

Answer (score 0):

a few assumptions

running apache on a linux box

check the httpd.conf as there is a default config that limits the "Allow" to localhost, plus the default config does not enable overrides (.htaccess files)

Answer (score 0):

On a Linux box? Check your `/etc/hosts`. The server has (probably) bound the listening address by hostname, which may (probably) be pointing at a 127.0.x.x address - try adding local entry by hostname for the real IPs of the machine and restarting the process.

Mark and cpbills are right that the `Host` header is probably causing you grief but this a good thing to check regardless as it *can* be a cause of the symptoms you describe.